# Install missing dependencies for scipy

Tags: python, installation, scipy

I'm trying to install scipy but when I finish installing, I can't import it. is there any GUI for easy installation? 
  The general information:
Windows 7 - Python 2.7 - scipy 0.11.0 - I followed the steps in abel.ee.ucla.edu/cvxopt/install/index.html) for windows to install the libraries needed. I ran the setup for scipy using python setup.py install in command line and in the setup.py directory. 
The error messege [error link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2hzrziuj2q18q4s/error.txt)

Comment: If the installation finished successfully, why do you want to do it again? The problem has to be somewhere else.

Comment: not successfully! It mostly complains about BLAS libraries, but I am sure I install BLAS successfully even though I can't find those libraries! part of the error : `blas_opt_info:
blas_mkl_info:
  libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in C:\Python27\lib
  libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in C:\
  libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in C:\Python27\libs
  NOT AVAILABLE atlas_blas_info:
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Python27\lib
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Python27\libs
  NOT AVAILABLE`

Comment: We need more information, are you under Linux/Windows/Mac ?, python version, scipy version, I would also like to see the steps you followed.

Comment: @f.ashouri You need to include this in the question. Also, change the title. You don't need a GUI installer for `scipy`. You need to install missing dependencies, that's all. Provide full error messages. Also +1 to request from _PepperoniPizza_.

Comment: Windows 7 - Python 2.7 - scipy 0.11.0 - I followed the steps in abel.ee.ucla.edu/cvxopt/install/index.html for windows to install the libraries needed. I ran the setup for scipy using `python setup.py install` in command line and in the setup.py directory.

Comment: No, there is no GUI installer.

Comment: full error messege in [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2hzrziuj2q18q4s/error.txt)

Comment: Please include all the relevant information (all that you've written in comments) in the question itself. This is the general rule: the question should be self-contained. The full error message text can be (preferably) included in the question, too.

Comment: You still didn't tell us how you installed BLAS libraries.

Comment: one of the steps here: abel.ee.ucla.edu/cvxopt/install/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a windows installer you can find one here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

But as it says: These are **unofficial**, **unsupported** and you might have to reinstall numpy and everything depending on numpy from there too!

**Read the instructions very careful!**